# How to say a verb has 'acted' on something

Tags: gramática, verbos

I am trying to figure out how to say how something/someone has done something or has had something happen to them in Spanish.

I am not sure how to put this properly, so here is an example:

> A string has to vibrate so that a sound can be created.

Here is how I would write this:

> Una cuerda tiene que reverberar asi que un sonido puede ser creado.

Did I use 'creado' correctly?  If I wanted to say a subject had been hit, or had been created, how do I take the verb golpear or crear and transform it into 'had been hit/created'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spanish [impersonal “se” constructions](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/impersonal-se-vs-passive-se) often serve the same purpose as the passive voice. Two literal translations of your sentence would be

> Una cuerda tiene que vibrar para que se pueda crear un sonido
>
> Una cuerda tiene que vibrar para que pueda crearse un sonido

But a more idiomatic sentence would be

> Una cuerda debe vibrar para poder producir un sonido
>
> A string must vibrate to be able to produce a sound

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for is the Spanish equivalent of the English [**past participle**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/past-participle)

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

> the form of a verb, usually made by adding -ed, used in some grammatical structures such as **the passive and the present perfect**.

That equivalent is the **participio**

According to the D.R.A.E

**[participio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S0EdlKH)**

> 2. m. Gram. Forma no personal del verbo, asimilada frecuentemente al adjetivo en su funcionamiento gramatical, que es susceptible de
>      recibir marcas de género y número y de participar en la **formación de
>      pasivas y otras perífrasis verbales**.

**participio activo**

> 2. m. Gram. participio que funciona como adjetivo y que se refiere al sustantivo ***como agente de la acción verbal***; p. ej., asomada en La niña
>      está asomada a la ventana.

I've highlighted in bold the part that matches what you have stated in the title of your question: **a verb has 'acted' on something**.

creado is the participio of the verb crear
golpeado is the participio of the verb golpear

As @arielCo has pointed the right translation of "so that" in your phrase is "para que", "así que" is not idiomatic in your context.